Updating the content in the Adobe Embed API Viewer
I am using the Adobe Embed API to display PDFs on my website. I have it working, but I am not able to find any way to reuse the viewer when I want to load a new PDF in the same session.
I was able to get it working if I just blew away the viewer instance. This feels like overkill, and like it would impact performance. This solution was mirrored here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-services-api-discussions/pdf-embed-api-replace-loaded-pdf-file/td-p/12353206
When I try to use the previewFile command the second time, it results in a mobx error:
await reportViewer.previewFile({
  content: { location: { url: docURL } },
  metaData: { fileName: 'dir.pdf' },
}, {
  autoSaveFrequency: 0,
  enableFocusPolling: false,
  showSaveButton: true,
  showAnnotationTools: false
});


Error: [mobx] Invariant failed: Since strict-mode is enabled,
changing observed observable values outside actions is not allowed.
Please wrap the code in an action if this change is intended.
Tried to modify: AppStore@1.isHidingBranding

Does anyone have any insight into the appropriate solution for this issue?
